# What is the difference between windows rdp version 4 vs 5 ?

Tags: linux

What is the difference between windows rdp version 4 vs 5 ?

I looking for a way to get a smoother steadier way to RDP from a Kali Linux into a remote Windows 7 workstation.

Right now just using basic rdesktop command is there a way to make the connection more consistent and less bandwidth intensive while keeping GUI ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol#Version_4.0 Wikipedia lists the features of each version.

Answer (score 1):

> I looking for a way to get a smoother steadier way to RDP from a Kali
>   Linux into a remote Windows 7 workstation.

If you want a smoother steadier experience, then you should be using an RDP 7.0 Client, numerous improvements were added that you will find helpful.  You can add RDP 8.0 can also be used, provided you have the required update.

> This version was released with Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2. A RDP 8.1 client update exists for Windows 7 SP1 as well, but unlike the RDP 8.0 update for Windows 7, it does not add a RDP 8.1 server component to Windows 7. Furthermore, if RDP 8.0 server function is desired on Windows 7, the KB 2592687 (RDP 8.0 client and server components) update must be installed before installing the RDP 8.1 update.

[Remote Desktop Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol#Version_4.0)

> What is the difference between windows RDP version 4 vs 5?

The primary difference between RDP 4.0 and RDP 5.0 was improved network bandwidth usage.  However, RDP has been updated numerous times, you should be using a client that supports RDP 7.0+

> Version 5.0
>
> This version was introduced with Windows 2000 Server, added support
>   for a number of features, including printing to local printers, and
>   aimed to improve network bandwidth usage.